# Querying facebook keywords containing parenthesis

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to query facebook keywords with the facebook ads api.
My problem is with keywords that contain parenthesis. I `urlencode` the string before I send it to facebook but it still won't work.
For example, if I want to query users who live in the U.S and like Apple inc., I query the following url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/act_19720295/targetingsentencelines?targeting_spec={%22countries%22:[%22US%22],%22keywords%22:[%22Apple+Inc.%22]}&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Which results the following:

```
{
   "params": {
      "countries": [
         "US"
      ],
      "keywords": [
         "apple inc"
      ]
   },
   "targetingsentencelines": [
      "who live in the United States",
      "who like apple inc"
   ]
}
```

If I add another keyword which contain parenthesis "App Store (iOS)", facebook ignores it:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/act_19720295/targetingsentencelines?targeting_spec={%22countries%22:[%22US%22],%22keywords%22:[%22Apple+Inc.%22,%22App+Store+%28iOS%29%22,%22%22]}&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

**And I still get the same result:**

```
{
   "params": {
      "countries": [
         "US"
      ],
      "keywords": [
         "apple inc"
      ]
   },
   "targetingsentencelines": [
      "who live in the United States",
      "who like apple inc"
   ]
}
```

Does anyone has any idea why??

Answer (score 1):

Adding the '#' char before the keyword ("#app store (ios)") solved the problem.